Seeking Insights for MSc Dissertation on EU's CBAM Impact on India: Challenges and Opportunities for Collaboration
Hello Economics Community,
I'm currently in the process of designing my MSc Economics dissertation and would greatly appreciate your insights. My focus is on the European Union's Carbon Border Adjustment Mechanism (CBAM) and its implications for Asian countries, with a particular emphasis on India. The core areas of my study aim to:
1. Quantify the Economic Impact: I plan to analyze how the CBAM could affect the Indian economy, considering trade dynamics and potential shifts in industry competitiveness.
2. Emissions Reduction Potential: I'm interested in estimating the
potential decrease in emissions if India aligns its policies to
complement the EU's CBAM, exploring avenues for mutual environmental
benefits.
3. Cost-Benefit Analysis: Part of my work will involve conducting a
cost-benefit analysis to evaluate the economic feasibility and
environmental benefits of India's potential adaptations to the CBAM.
4. Trade Group Dynamics: I also wish to examine how trade groups and
alliances might influence or obstruct the execution and
effectiveness of the CBAM, particularly in the context of Asian
economies.
Given the complexity and multidisciplinary nature of this topic, I'm reaching out for suggestions on:
- Economic Theories and Models: Which economic theories and models would be most pertinent for analyzing the impact of the CBAM on trade, emissions, and economic policy in India?
- Methodological Approaches: Are there specific quantitative or qualitative methods that you would recommend for this type of analysis? Any particular data sources or econometric models that could be especially useful?
- Case Studies or Precedents: Are there examples of similar environmental policies impacting international trade relations that might offer insights or comparative analyses for my dissertation?
- Potential Challenges: What major challenges do you foresee in conducting this research, and how might I address them?
I'm eager to incorporate a diverse range of perspectives and methodologies to ensure a comprehensive analysis. Any advice, references, or suggestions you could share would be immensely helpful as I refine my research proposal.
Thank you for your time and expertise!
